# Yet another elmah problem ... works everywhere but production

Tags: elmah

I have elmah setup to use SqlErrorLog and this is running fine on both my local using the developer webserver, and my integration environment under IIS. On my production box elmah is able to log exceptions with XmlFileErrorLog writting to the app_data directory. When I switch back to SqlErrorLog I get nadda. I have ensured that the database exists has the required table and three procedures. I have tested the connectionstring. I have compared the web.configs from my local to prod and the only differences are the database server name in the connection strings.

Any thoughts as to what else can be blocking in a production installation?

~-=Mike=-~

Answer (score 0):

Have you properly setup the permissions on the database for ELMAH? Depending on if you are you using impersonation with your web application, you may have to grant privileges to additional users to the stored procedures/tables.

Comment: I'm using sql authentication so the user name and password are in the connection string. I don't see any differences in my permissions set on any of my other tables or procs than exists on the elmah table and procs. I moved everything inside my primary database from the Elmah default database as a troubleshooting step for this problem. Everything else is able to talk to this database from this website except elmah.

Comment: Hmm... Is anything getting spit out into the SQL Logs, the IIS Logs, or the Event Viewer Logs that indicates problems?

Comment: Sql logs -> no; IIS logs -> I see 302s for the test exception; and Event Logs -> I see the test exception here too. Nothing else looks out of the ordinary ... I'm going to try profiler next. See if it is talking to it.

Comment: Profiler results show nothing is being called to the database.

Comment: Ugh, my only next thought would be to run RegMon/FileMon or Process Monitor on it to see if something weird is erroring out, but you'd need to be on the web server when that gets fired up.

Comment: [:: smiles ::] No worries. Any progress? I'm running a blank.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. I have impersonation and everything configured properly but it still is attempting to connect to the database as ANONYMOUS. Any help would be appreciated.